# How to get a table without internal justification of the text and that fits on the sheet?

Tags: tables, macros, multirow, colortbl

The table distorted with unjustified text that does not fit the size of the sheet.

In the table the text of the multi-row cell is not justified, in addition, the table has to distort the size of the table outside the dimensions of the sheet.

Attached image 1 the configuration of the table, it is shown in the image (without background color, in the code the background color and text were added).
[image]

Here is the code and errors (image 2)

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
% Pictures & Labels
%%\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{xcolor}
 \usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{adjustbox} %%este es para hacer ajustes automáticos de tablas
\usepackage{longtable} % tablas grandes 
\usepackage{array} % no need for 'multirow' package, really
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}} % is this right?
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
% Paper Style
\usepackage[letterpaper,centering]{geometry} %%paquete para cambiar diseño de pagina
\usepackage[title,toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
% like \newgeometry, but also allows change of landscape/portrait and paper size
% to be used with caution!
\newcommand{\newgeometryfull}[1]{%
  \clearpage
  \Gm@restore@org
  \Gm@initnewgm
%  \Gm@newgmtrue
  \setkeys{Gm}{#1}%
%  \Gm@newgmfalse
  \Gm@process
  \ifnum\mag=\@m\else\Gm@magtooffset\fi
  \Gm@changelayout
  \Gm@showparams{newgeometry}}%
\makeatother

%% Allow A3 sheets - - establecemos las características del A3
\newenvironment{a3mypage}{%
    \newgeometryfull{paperwidth=431.8mm,paperheight=279.4mm,centering,hmargin=31.75mm,top=25.4 mm,bottom=25.4 mm}
    % set the correct dimension for the PDF viewer
    \pdfpageheight=\paperheight
    \pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth}
{  \restoregeometry
    % set the correct dimension for the PDF viewer
    \pdfpageheight=\paperheight
    \pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth} %termina la edicion de la hoja A3
\newcommand\PBS[1]{\let\temp=\\%
  #1%
  \let\\=\temp
}
 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize\bfseries\color{blue}}

\begin{document}
\begin{a3mypage}
\section{Cronograma de actividades: Gantt}

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{p{0.179\textwidth}p{0.179\textwidth}p{0.179\textwidth}p{0.132\textwidth}p{0.179\textwidth}p{0.152\textwidth}}
\rowcolor[rgb]{0.808,0.576,0.847} \textbf{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0.545}{TITULO:}} & \multicolumn{5}{l}{\textbf{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0.545}{DISEÑO DE UN DESHIDRATADOR TEXTURIZADOR AL VACÍO PARA DISMINUIR EL TIEMPO DE DESHIDRATADO CONSERVANDO LAS PROPIEDADES DEL AÇAÍ}}} \\
PROBLEMAS & OBJETIVOS & HIPOTESIS & VARIABLES & INDICADORES & METODOLOGÍA \\
\rowcolor[rgb]{0.882,0.745,0.906} \textbf{\textcolor{blue}{Problema general (principal)}} & \textbf{\textcolor{blue}{Objetivo general (principal)}} & \textcolor{blue}{\textbf{Hipótesis~general (principal)}} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{\textcolor{blue}{Variable Independiente (VI)}}} & \textbf{\textcolor{blue}{Tipo de investigación}} \\
\rowcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961} {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}} & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}} & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{DISEÑAR UN DESHIDRATADOR AL VACÍO QUE APLIQUE TRATAMIENTO DE TEXTURIZADO} & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}} \\
\rowcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961} {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}} & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}} & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}} & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}} & Temperatura de deshidratado & \multirow{-2}{*}{{\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}}Investigación  tecnológica aplicada} \\
\rowcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961} {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}} & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}} & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}} & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}} & Presión de Vacío & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.882,0.745,0.906}}\textbf{\textcolor{blue}{Diseño de la investigación}} \\
\rowcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961} {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}} & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}} & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}} & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}} & Capacidad de deshidratado & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}} \\
\rowcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961} {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}} & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}} & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}} & \multirow{-4}{*}{{\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}}Variables o parámetros de diseño y capacidad de deshidratado} & Proceso de deshidratacion & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}} \\
\rowcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961} {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}} & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}} & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}} & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}} & Modulos para el deshidratado al vacio & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}} \\
\rowcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961} {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}} & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}} & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}} & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}} & Modulo para el tratamiento de testurizado & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}} \\
\rowcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961} {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}} & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}} & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}} & \multirow{-3}{*}{{\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}}Componentes modulares de deshidratador al vacío con tratamiento de texturizado} & Modulo de Control y automatizacion de deshidratador texturizador & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}} \\
\rowcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961} {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}} & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}} & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}} & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}} & Diseño CAD de los componentes modulares. & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}} \\
\rowcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961} {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}} & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}} & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}} & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}} & Planos de los componentes modulares. & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}} \\
\rowcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961} {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}} & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}} & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}} & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}} & Ficha tenica del deshidratadortexturizador al vacío & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}} \\
\rowcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961} \multirow{-12}{*}{{\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}}¿Es factible diseñar un deshidratador al vacío que aplique tratamiento de texturizado para disminuir el tiempo de deshidratado sin perder las propiedades antioxidantes y sensoriales del Açaí?} & \multirow{-12}{*}{{\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}}DISEÑAR UN DESHIDRATADOR AL VACIO QUE APLIQUE TRATAMIENTO DE TEXTURIZADO PARA DISMINUIR EL TIEMPO DE DESHIDRATADO CONSERVANDO LAS PROPIEDADES NUTRICIONALES, ANTIOXIDANTES Y SENSORIALES DEL AÇAÍ} & \multirow{-12}{*}{{\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}}El diseño de un deshidratador al vacío que aplique tratamiento de texturizado disminuye el tiempo de deshidratado sin perder las propiedades antioxidantes y sensoriales del Açaí} & \multirow{-4}{*}{{\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}}Diseño de los componentes modulares de deshidratador al vacío con tratamiento de texturizado} & Resultados de analisis CAD de los componentes modulares & \multirow{-9}{*}{{\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}}Método experimental, y se aplicará a la variable independinete para luego medir sus efectos en la variable dependiente poer medio de los indicadores(cantidad de antioxidantes, costo de equipo y viabilidad economico)} \\
\rowcolor[rgb]{0.882,0.745,0.906} \textcolor{blue}{\textbf{Problema especificos (secundario)}} & \textcolor{blue}{\textbf{Objetivos especificos (secundario)}} & \textcolor{blue}{\textbf{Hipotesis especifico (secundario)}} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textcolor{blue}{\textbf{Variable Independiente (VI)}}} & \textbf{\textcolor{blue}{Instrumento}} \\
\rowcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961} {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}} & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}} & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{DISMINUIR EL TIEMPO DE DESHIDRATADO CONSERVANDO LAS PROPIEDADES ANTIOXIDANTES Y SENSORIALES DEL ACAI} & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}} \\
\rowcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961} \multirow{-2}{*}{{\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}}¿ Es factible determinar las variables o parametros de diseño y la capacidad de carga para el proceso de deshidratación del Acai?} & \multirow{-2}{*}{{\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}}Determinar las variables o parámetros de diseño y la capacidad de carga de un equipo deshidratador texturizador que disminuye el tiempo de deshidratado conservando las propiedades del Açaí} & \multirow{-2}{*}{{\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}}Las variables o parametros de diseño y la capacidad de cargade un equipo deshidratador texturizador que disminuye el tiempo de deshidratado conservando las propiedades del Açaí} & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.882,0.745,0.906}}\textcolor{blue}{\textbf{Dimensiones}} & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.882,0.745,0.906}}\textcolor{blue}{\textbf{Indicadores}} & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}} \\
\rowcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961} {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}} & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}} & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}} & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}} & Contenido de antioxidantes (ORAC) y polifenoles del Acai & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}} \\
\rowcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961} \multirow{-2}{*}{{\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}}¿ Es factiblela indentificar los componentes modulares del equipo deshidratador texturizador que conserve las nutricionales, antioxidantes y sensoriales del Acai?} & \multirow{-2}{*}{{\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}}Identificar los componentes modulares de un equipo deshidratador texturizador que disminuye el tiempo de deshidratado conservando las propiedades del Açaí} & \multirow{-2}{*}{{\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}}Los componentes modulares del equipo deshidratador texturizador de un equipo deshidratador texturizador que disminuye el tiempo de deshidratado conservando las propiedades del Açaí} & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}} & Eficiencia de deshidratador texturizador & \multirow{-4}{*}{{\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}}Manuales, fichas tecnicas, normas tecnicas, hojas de calculo, ensayos de laboratorio de compuesto antioxidante, software de diseño y analisis, etc.} \\
\rowcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961} {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}} & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}} & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}} & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}} & Tiempo de deshidratado con tratamiento y sin tratamiento de texturizado. & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.882,0.745,0.906}}\textbf{\textcolor{blue}{Población de estudio}} \\
\rowcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961} \multirow{-2}{*}{{\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}}¿Es factiblediseñar los ompoenentes modualres del deshidratador texturizador de capacidad identificada para el Acai?} & \multirow{-2}{*}{{\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}}Diseñar los componentes modulares de un equipo deshidratador texturizador que disminuye el tiempo de deshidratado conservando las propiedades del Açaí} & \multirow{-2}{*}{{\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}}El diseño de los componentes modulares de un equipo deshidratador texturizador que disminuye el tiempo de deshidratado conservando las propiedades del Açaí} & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}} & Factibilidad tecnica. & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}} \\
\rowcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961} {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}} & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}} & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}} & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}} & Factibilidad economica & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}} \\
\rowcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961} \multirow{-2}{*}{{\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}}¿Es factible evaluar la factibilidad tenica y economica de un equipo deshidratador texturizador que disminuye el tiempo de deshidratado conservando las propiedades del Acai} & \multirow{-2}{*}{{\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}}Evaluar la factibilidad técnica y económica de un equipo deshidratador texturizador que disminuye el tiempo de deshidratado conservando las propiedades del Açaí} & \multirow{-2}{*}{{\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}}La factibilidad tecnica y economica de un equipo deshidratador texturizador que diminuye el tiempo de deshidratado conservando las propiedades del Açaí} & \multirow{-6}{*}{{\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}}Factibilidad tecnica y economica de un equipo deshidratador texturizador que disminuye el tiempo de deshidratado conservando las propiedades del Açaí} & Factiibilidad financiera. & \multirow{-3}{*}{{\cellcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}}Tipos de deshidratadores presentes en la industria alimentaria y de otros procesos}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{a3mypage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! For start point I suggest you the following: **(i)** remove all commands for coloring of cells, **(ii)**  in all muktirow cells replace `{*}` with `{=}`. After this see id your  table is close to what you like to have. Colors, if they are really needed, you can add later when tale layout is as is desired.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you could change your table code in order to make sure the texts fit into their respective cells while at the same time making sure the table is exactly as wide as the available textwidth. I also tried to provide a bit more visual structure by using alternating row colors.

Here is a MWE for the upper half of your table:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
% Pictures & Labels
%%\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
 \usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
%\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{adjustbox} %%este es para hacer ajustes automáticos de tablas
\usepackage{longtable} % tablas grandes 
\usepackage{array} % no need for 'multirow' package, really
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}} % is this right?
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
% Paper Style
\usepackage[letterpaper,centering]{geometry} %%paquete para cambiar diseño de pagina
\usepackage[title,toc,page]{appendix}
%%\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
% like \newgeometry, but also allows change of landscape/portrait and paper size
% to be used with caution!
\newcommand{\newgeometryfull}[1]{%
  \clearpage
  \Gm@restore@org
  \Gm@initnewgm
%  \Gm@newgmtrue
  \setkeys{Gm}{#1}%
%  \Gm@newgmfalse
  \Gm@process
  \ifnum\mag=\@m\else\Gm@magtooffset\fi
  \Gm@changelayout
  \Gm@showparams{newgeometry}}%
\makeatother

%% Allow A3 sheets - - establecemos las características del A3
\newenvironment{a3mypage}{%
    \newgeometryfull{paperwidth=431.8mm,paperheight=279.4mm,centering,hmargin=31.75mm,top=25.4 mm,bottom=25.4 mm}
    % set the correct dimension for the PDF viewer
    \pdfpageheight=\paperheight
    \pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth}
{  \restoregeometry
    % set the correct dimension for the PDF viewer
    \pdfpageheight=\paperheight
    \pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth} %termina la edicion de la hoja A3
\newcommand\PBS[1]{\let\temp=\\%
  #1%
  \let\\=\temp
}
 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\bfseries\color{blue}}


\begin{document}
\begin{a3mypage}
\section{Cronograma de actividades: Gantt}


{\small
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*{6}{X}} %%tabla
%---------------------------------------------------
\rowcolor[rgb]{0.808,0.576,0.847} 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0.545}{\textbf{TITULO:}}} 
& \multicolumn{5}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr5\hsize+8\tabcolsep}X}{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0.545}{\textbf{DISEÑO DE UN DESHIDRATADOR TEXTURIZADOR AL VACÍO PARA DISMINUIR EL TIEMPO DE DESHIDRATADO CONSERVANDO LAS PROPIEDADES DEL AÇAÍ}}} \\ %% titulo de tabla
 \multicolumn{1}{c}{\thead{PROBLEMAS}} 
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\thead{OBJETIVOS}} 
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\thead{HIPOTESIS}} 
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\thead{VARIABLES}} 
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\thead{INDICADORES}} 
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\thead{METODOLOGÍA}} \\ %%subtitulo 1 de tabla
 
\rowcolor[rgb]{0.882,0.745,0.906} 
\thead{Problema general\\ (principal)} 
& \thead{Objetivo general\\ (principal)} 
& \thead{Hipotesis general\\ (principal)} 
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{\colorbox[rgb]{0.882,0.745,0.906}{\thead{Variable Independiente (VI)}}} 
& \thead{Tipo de investigación}\\ %% subtitulo 2
 
\rowcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}  
&  
&  
& \multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep}X}{Diseñar un deshidratador al vacío que aplique tratamiento de texturizado} 
& \\

\rowcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}
& 
& 
& \cellcolor{white} 
& \cellcolor{white} Temperatura de deshidratado 
& \multirow{-3}{=}{Investigación  tecnológica aplicada} \\

\rowcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}  
& 
& 
& \cellcolor{white}
& Presión de Vacío 
& \thead{\cellcolor[rgb]{0.882,0.745,0.906}Diseño de la investigación} \\

\rowcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961} 
& 
& 
& \cellcolor{white} 
& \cellcolor{white} Capacidad de deshidratado 
&  \\

\rowcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}
&  
&  
& \multirow{-4}{=}{\cellcolor{white} Variables o parámetros de diseño y capacidad de deshidratado} 
& Proceso de deshidratacion 
&  \\

\rowcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}
&  
&  
&  
& \cellcolor{white} Modulos para el deshidratado al vacio 
&  \\

\rowcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}  
&  
& 
&  
& Modulo para el tratamiento de testurizado 
&  \\

\rowcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}
&  
&  
& \multirow{-4}{=}{Componentes modulares de deshidratador al vacío con tratamiento de texturizado} 
& \cellcolor{white} Modulo de Control y automatizacion de deshidratador texturizador 
&  \\

\rowcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}
&  
&  
& \cellcolor{white} 
& Diseño CAD de los componentes modulares. 
& \\

\rowcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961} 
&  
&  
& \cellcolor{white}
& \cellcolor{white} Planos de los componentes modulares. 
&  \\

\rowcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961} 
& 
& 
& \cellcolor{white}
& Ficha tenica del deshidratadortexturizador al vacío 
& \\

\rowcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}
\multirow{-20}{=}{¿Es factible diseñar un deshidratador al vacío que aplique tratamiento de texturizado para disminuir el tiempo de deshidratado sin perder las propiedades antioxidantes y sensoriales del Açaí?} 
& \multirow{-20}{=}{DISEÑAR UN DESHIDRATADOR AL VACIO QUE APLIQUE TRATAMIENTO DE TEXTURIZADO PARA DISMINUIR EL TIEMPO DE DESHIDRATADO CONSERVANDO LAS PROPIEDADES NUTRICIONALES, ANTIOXIDANTES Y SENSORIALES DEL AÇAÍ} 
& \multirow{-20}{=}{El diseño de un deshidratador al vacío que aplique tratamiento de texturizado disminuye el tiempo de deshidratado sin perder las propiedades antioxidantes y sensoriales del Açaí} 
& \multirow{-6}{=}{\cellcolor{white} Diseño de los componentes modulares de deshidratador al vacío con tratamiento de texturizado} 
& \cellcolor{white} Resultados de analisis CAD de los componentes modulares 
& \multirow{-16}{=}{Método experimental, y se aplicará a la variable independinete para luego medir sus efectos en la variable dependiente poer medio de los indicadores(cantidad de antioxidantes, costo de equipo y viabilidad economico)} \\
\end{tabularx}
}
\end{a3mypage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: the most of `\cellcolor` are superfluous. The are alread covered by `rowcolor`.

Comment: @Zarko: You're right. I just updated my answer accordingly and tried to simplify the code as much as possible by replacing repeated `\cellcolor` commands with appropriate `\rowcolor` commands.

Comment: Thanks a lot. and, how to justify the content within each cell?

Comment: @ReyesReyesEmerzon, as far as I can see, contents of cells are now justified accordingly.  You should consider my comment below your question. In this may be of help to temporary introduc vertical and horizontal lines accordingly, that you can see, where are your cells (number of spanned lines in multirow cells are in your MWE mostly wrong).  leandriis did excellent job (+1). BTW, such colored tables are (at least of my taste) ugly. Reconsider, what you like to have. See https://wiert.me/2014/04/03/andre-vatter-google-wie-tabellen-eigentlich-aussehen-sollten-%EF%BB%BF/

Comment: Justified text instead of left aligned text inside of the `\multirow` commands will lead to quite large white spaces between adjacent words as the columns are comparably narrow. If you nevertheless want justified text, you could add `\justify ` inside of each `\multirow` command.

Comment: @ leandriis, Thanks.